# Docker flask application environment variables

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, docker, environment-variables

I'm starting a docker container the following way:

```
docker run -e IP_AD=192.168.99.100 -p 80:80 flask_app
```

I'm simply trying to pass an IP Address to the flask application so that something can be loaded from my application. This resource will change from environment to environment, so this is the reason I would like to pass it as an environment variable.

Later, I would like to use this variable but from the context of the running flask application. How can I load `IP_AD` from my flask application and use it as a python variable?

I've tried doing this:

```
import os
os.environ.get('IP_AD')
```

But it does not seem to be loading anything. What is the correct way to load IP_AD passed from docker run -e

Comment: `-e` is correct e.g., `docker run --rm -e ENV=1 python python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["ENV"])'`

Comment: Your suggestion works. my problem was I was not passing my ip address as a string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create file .env like this

```
model_path=./model/data_fs.csv
```

then install library `.env` by doing

```
pip3 install python-dotenv==0.17.1
```

add this to your code to load all your `.env` variable

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

so you can access it

```
if os.getenv("model_path", None) is not None:
    return os.getenv("model_path", None)
# otherwise raise an exception
raise Exception("no .env file found")
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to put `env` variable before command so that it can be accessed from flask application.

Let me give some example, I have example flask in here

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["OPTIONS", "GET"])
def home():
    IP_AD = os.environ.get("IP_AD")
    return jsonify({"status": 200, "message": IP_AD})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then when running by using `env` variable you could do this

```
IP_AD=192.168.99.100 python main.py
```

So then, when you trying to access the `env` variable it will showing like this, example by using curl

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:5000'
```

response will be like this

```
{"message":"192.168.99.100","status":200}
```

---

So in your case it will be

```
IP_AD=192.168.99.100 docker run -e -p 80:80 flask_app
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try like this

```
import os
os.environ["IP_AD"]
```

Comment: This answer copies one from the first comment.